# trying to update quantity change in a form php

Tags: php

please i am trying to make an update in a database where changes have been made to quantity,but i need a guide where the change is update is only made to where the change is done.

this is the code where the changes would be done

```
<?
    $pplresult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM repplac");
    echo "<table border='1'><tr><th> SHOP NAME</th><th> PRODUCT NAME</th><th>
    PRODUCT SIZE</th><th> PRODUCT COLOUR</th><th> PRODUCT QUANTITY</th><th>
    PRICE</th><th> </th></tr>";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($pplresult)){?>
<form action='updatepplac.php' method='Post' class='slistbar'>
<?echo "<tr><td>" .$row['Sname'] ."</td><td>" .$row['Pname'] ."</td><td>" .$row['Psize'] ."</td><td>" .$row['Pcolour'] ."</td><td>" ."<input type='text' name='Pquantity' id='Pquantity' value='{$row['Pquantity']}' >" ."</td><td>" .$row['Price'] ."</td><td>" ?>
<a href="deleteproduct.php?del=<?php echo $row['Pidno'];?>">delete</a></td></tr><?php }
// table closing tag
?>
```

and the update script

```
$submit = $_POST['submit'];
        $pid = $_GET['del'];
        $nPquantity = $_POST['Pquantity'];
        //echo "$nPquantity";

        //die();
        if('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
        {
        $queryreg = mysql_query("
        UPDATE repplac SET Pquantity='$nPquantity' ")or die(mysql_error());
        }
```

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to both sql injections and XSS also mysql_error() will give the attacker info about current tables...

Answer (score 0):

You need here `UPDATE repplac SET Pquantity='$nPquantity'` a condition with `WHERE id=your_row_id` otherwise where do you update?

EDIT: should look like this

```
$queryreg = mysql_query("
    UPDATE repplac SET Pquantity=".mysql_real_escape_string($nPquantity)." WHERE id = ".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['edit_id']))or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

UPDATE: when your user clicks the link to edit that you need to add the uid of the field that is edited like this:

```
 <a href='edit.php?edit_id=<?php echo $your_row_id; ?>'>edit link</a>
```

After that read once more the query since I added the GET variable there.

Comment: yes i know, i did not specify the where the update is to be done, where i am lost is ow will i specify where the row id is changed, and also when i echoed the post dat of where quantity change was done, it oly came back with the result of the last row changed

Comment: please i am having problems posting my questions its giving this message

Comment: Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

    Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: then put 4 spaces in front of each line of your code or select the code and then click the code button which is this one "{}". Did the first answer work for you?

Comment: i am still having problem in my upgrade script

Comment: close this question then and open another one with the current problem

Comment: i tried asking and it says i cant any more, have i done anything wrong somewher